# can't adapt type 'data'

Tags: python, postgresql, list

I have data class:

```
class data: 
def __init__(self, ReadTime, Concentration_PM10, Concentration_SO2, Concentration_O3, Concentration_NO2, Concentration_CO, AQI_PM10,
             AQI_SO2,AQI_O3, AQI_NO2, AQI_CO, AQI_AQIIndex, AQI_ContaminantParameter, AQI_State, AQI_Color ): 
    self.ReadTime = ReadTime 
    self.Concentration_PM10 = Concentration_PM10 
    self.Concentration_SO2 = Concentration_SO2
    self.Concentration_O3 = Concentration_O3 
    self.Concentration_NO2 = Concentration_NO2
    self.Concentration_CO = Concentration_CO 
    self.AQI_PM10 = AQI_PM10
    self.AQI_SO2 = AQI_SO2 
    self.AQI_O3 = AQI_O3
    self.AQI_NO2 = AQI_NO2 
    self.AQI_CO = AQI_CO
    self.AQI_AQIIndex = AQI_AQIIndex 
    self.AQI_ContaminantParameter = AQI_ContaminantParameter
    self.AQI_State = AQI_State 
    self.AQI_Color = AQI_Color
```

I'm sending a request to an api and populating the variables into a list.:

```
list = [] 
for i in result:
list.append( data(i['ReadTime'], i['Concentration']['PM10'], i['Concentration']['SO2'],i['Concentration']['O3'],
                   i['Concentration']['NO2'],i['Concentration']['CO'],i['AQI']['PM10'],
            i['AQI']['SO2'],i['AQI']['O3'],i['AQI']['NO2'],i['AQI']['CO'],i['AQI']['AQIIndex'],i['AQI']['ContaminantParameter'],
            i['AQI']['State'],i['AQI']['Color']))
```

then I want to insert this list into a table in PostgreSQL but I get error "can't adapt type 'data'"

```
list_record = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(list))
query_insert= (f"INSERT INTO hava_kalitesi (ReadTime, Concentration_PM10, Concentration_SO2, Concentration_O3, Concentration_NO2, Concentration_CO, AQI_PM10, AQI_SO2, AQI_O3, AQI_NO2, AQI_CO, AQI_AQIIndex, AQI_ContaminantParameter,AQI_State,AQI_Color) VALUES {list_record}"
)
cursor.execute(query_insert,list)
```

Comment: First do use `f` strings to build a query, this leaves you open to SQL injection.  See [psycopg2 parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Second see [Python adapation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), `psycopg2` has no idea what to do with `data` class. Third,  the `data` class is just duplication of effort, just use a list of lists. See here [execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) .

Comment: Hmm, stronger coffee is in order. That should have been, 'First do not use f strings ...'.